# Using MongoDB Stitch webhook service function, how can I convert the returned "insertedId" to string?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-stitch

I'm creating MongoDB Stitch http services (using the 3rd Party Services > Incoming Webhooks > Function Editor) for a simple CRUD application and I am trying to insertOne() document and then return the document id as a string.

The insertion works as expected and I await the result and store it in a variable.

```
const result = await collection.insertOne(payload.query)
const id = result.insertedId
```

The problem is trying to convert this `id` to string. I'm guessing it's due to my lack of understanding the MongoDB Extended JSON and BSON types, etc. I've read all parts of the documentation that I thought could provide a solution here.

I've tried the following to convert the return value to a string:

```
id.toString() // logs as a string, but is an object { $oid: '507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e' }
id.valueOf() // logs as a string, but is an object { $oid: '507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e' }
id['$oid'] // undefined
Object.values(id.insertedId) // throws error: {"message":"'values' is not a function"}
id.str // undefined
result.str // undefined
```

Not sure what else to try and would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction here to provide a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution after noticing this section of the documentation: 
[MONGODB STITCH > Functions > Reference > JSON & BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/functions/json-and-bson/#EJSON.stringify)

```
const result = await collection.insertOne(payload.query)
const id = JSON.stringify(
  JSON.parse(
    EJSON.stringify(result.insertedId)
  ).$oid
).replace(/\W/g,'');
```

Seems a bit hacky just for getting the id of the document into a string, but it will work for now.